# r search value in row

Tags: r, count

how can I search for specific values in a line. E.g., for this data

```
 a <- c("a", "a", "b", "c")
 b <- c("b", "a", "b", "d")
 c <- c("c", "a", "b", "c")
 d <- c("a", "a", "b", "a")
 x <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
 head(x)
```

I would like to know if there is an "a", "b", "c", or "d" in the first row. The optimal result would look like additional columns that indicate how many are in each row.

Thanks again!

Comment: Please include the example output you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do:

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(melt(as.matrix(x))[,c(1,3)]))
cbind(x,df1)
#  a b c d a b c d
#1 a b c a 2 1 1 0
#2 a a a a 4 0 0 0
#3 b b b b 0 4 0 0
#4 c d c a 1 0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach sticking to base:

```
f<-function(x) table(factor(unlist(x),levels=letters[1:4]))
df1<-t(apply(x,1,f))
cbind(x,df1)

  a b c d a b c d
1 a b c a 2 1 1 0
2 a a a a 4 0 0 0
3 b b b b 0 4 0 0
4 c d c a 1 0 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to J.R.'s answer, but a little bit different:

```
s <- split(unlist(x), rep.int(seq_len(nrow(x)), nrow(x)))    
cbind(x, do.call(rbind, Map(table, s)))
#   a b c d a b c d
# 1 a b c a 2 1 1 0
# 2 a a a a 4 0 0 0
# 3 b b b b 0 4 0 0
# 4 c d c a 1 0 2 1
```

`vapply` might actually be better (and faster) here:

```
cbind(x, t(vapply(s, table, integer(4L))))
#   a b c d a b c d
# 1 a b c a 2 1 1 0
# 2 a a a a 4 0 0 0
# 3 b b b b 0 4 0 0
# 4 c d c a 1 0 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? Not totally clear what you want the output to look like

```
x$A <- apply(x,1,function(x) length(grep("a",x)))
x$B <- apply(x,1,function(x) length(grep("b",x)))
x$C <- apply(x,1,function(x) length(grep("c",x)))
x$D <- apply(x,1,function(x) length(grep("d",x)))

> x
 a b c d A B C D
 1 a b c a 2 1 1 0
 2 a a a a 4 0 0 0
 3 b b b b 0 4 0 0
 4 c d c a 1 0 2 1
```